# Self-hosted server that checks for visually similar images in its database

Tags: images, database, image-processing, self-hosted, comparison

at the moment we are using an server application named "iskdaemon (imgseek daemon)" which is installed on a debian linux server. But the server is kind of unstable and it's problematic to maintain this software.
https://github.com/ricardocabral/iskdaemon

We use it to initially index all picture files which we have already in another database, and to let users visual check new added images if similar images have been already imported (aka "content-based (visual) image searching"). 
This comparison is done via an API.

Do you know a good alternate server software which can do this?
Possibly running under Windows?

Comment: Hey there, is there no alternate software?